# Setting up FastCGI with SCRIPT_FILENAME

Tags: python, nginx, fastcgi, nginx-config

I've been going back and forth with my nginx/fastcgi set up for a couple hours now, but it seems that it is nearly impossible to properly debug my configuration.

My configuration files are as follows:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite:

```
server {
        server_name example.com;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                alias /var/www/favicon.ico;
        }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/ben/servers/website/noot;
        }
        location /old/ {
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
        include fcgiwrap.conf;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
```

/etc/nginx/fcgiwrap.conf:

```
location ~* \.(py|cgi)$ {
  # Disable gzip (it makes scripts feel slower since they have to complete
  # before getting gzipped)
  gzip off;

  # Fastcgi socket
  fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;

  # Fastcgi parameters, include the standard ones
  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

  # Adjust non standard parameters (SCRIPT_FILENAME)
  # change
  #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/old/index.cgi;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

/var/www/html/old/index.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
print "<html>\n<body>"
print "<div style=\"width: 100%; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;\">"
print "Python Script Test Page"
print "</div>\n</body>\n</html>"
```

However, when I visit /old/index.cgi it gives a 403 error: Forbidden.

It also outputs `FastCGI sent in stderr: "Cannot get script name, are DOCUMENT_ROOT and SCRIPT_NAME (or SCRIPT_FILENAME) set and is the script executable?" while reading response header from upstream` in nginx's error log.

However, if I switch which line is commented out in the fcgiwrap.conf file it seems to function perfectly, indicating that the issue is likely to do with the SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter. I can't figure out how to determine where it's trying to access, nor why this setup should fail to access the appropriate file. I tried commenting out both lines setting the SCRIPT_FILENAME parameter and that gave the same 403 result.

Comment: Move the `include fcgiwrap.conf;` statement into the `location /old/` block so that the value of `$document_root` is set for FastCGI URIs beginning with `/old/`.

Comment: @RichardSmith That's exactly it, thank you. I had assumed that those variables would be resolved effectively as a file was fetched somehow, so it would choose the relevant document root - obviously I was thinking about this in entirely the wrong way. If you want to put something down as an answer, I'll more than happily mark it as correct.